# How can you configure the base url for Spring Boot Actuator so it is returned by the base endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot's actuator base endpoint returns json with href links for all enabled endpoints.  The links all default to localhost:8080 but I am authenticated with a hostname such as machine.mydomain.com.

How can I get the links to populate with https://machine.mydomain.com instead of http://localhost:8090 ?

Example output from actuator when I visit
https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator

```
/ 20181012150557
// https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator

{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator",
      "templated": false
    },
    "beans": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/beans",
      "templated": false
    },
    "health": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health",
      "templated": false
    }
}
```

What I want is
    / 20181012150557
    // https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator",
      "templated": false
    },
    "beans": {
      "href": "https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator/beans",
      "templated": false
    },
    "health": {
      "href": "https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator/health",
      "templated": false
    }
}
```

Comment: create "A" record for machine.mydomain.com to your public ip where application is installed, run your app to 443 and make sure setup ssl properties for your spring boot application should give you endpoint what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I need more detail to explain my setup.  I already have the domain correctly configured on my machine and 'https://machine.mydomain.com/' resolves correctly to my application.  I have apache serving the ssl https and forwarding to my tomcat application running on localhost:8080.  That is why the actuator url has localhost:8080.  But you can notice in my original post that the url I reached actuator on was 'https://machine.mydomain.com/actuator' and yet the links inside the returned json area all using localhost:8080 which is what I want to fix.

Comment: I think setting up server.address=    property in application.properties should solve your purpose but make sure to make a entry in hosts file for your subdomain

Comment: Tried setting server.address=machine.mydomain.com
But nothing changes on the main page still shows localhost:8090

I also tried the more actuator specific
management.server.address=
same result, no change

Comment: @RonaldGouldnerJr I just ran into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with my application. Spring Boot uses the current request URL to generate the hypermedia links on the actuator main page.

See `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping`:

```
@Override
@ResponseBody
protected Map<String, Map<String, Link>> links(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    return Collections.singletonMap("_links",
            this.linksResolver.resolveLinks(request.getRequestURL().toString()));
}
```

If you are behind a proxy (Apache, nginx) the real request URL may be moved to `X-Forwarded-*` headers. The easiest solution is to add Spring's `ForwardedHeaderFilter` for the actuator endpoints like this:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> filter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
    filter.setName("Forwarded Header filter");
    filter.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singletonList("/actuator/*"));
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Your solution is working.  Thanks.  At first I missed the /actuator/* in the code and forgot to change to the context I am using.  Now that I have switched this works well.

Comment: As for 2019 there is boolean configuration property _server.use-forward-headers_. It is javadoc-ed as _"Whether X-Forwarded-* headers should be applied to the HttpRequest"_. For _tomcat_ it is used to configure _RemoteIpValve_

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.2 the `server.use-forward-headers` was deprecated in favor of `server.forward-headers-strategy`. More info here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-22